# Issue with image load recursive chain on slow network/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, callback

So basically I have a page with a few sections.  Each sections contains 5-30 image icons that are fairly small in size but large enough that I want to manipulate the load order of them.

I'm using a library called collagePlus which allows me to give it a list of elements which it will collage into a nice image grid.  The idea here is to start at the first section of images, load the images, display the grid, then move on to the next section of images all the way to the end.  Once we reach the end I pass a callback which initializes a gallery library I am using called fancybox which simply makes all the images interactive when clicked(but does not modify the icons state/styles).

```
var fancyCollage = new function() { /* A mixed usage of fancybox.js and collagePlus.js */
    var collageOpts = {
        'targetHeight': 200,
        'fadeSpeed': 2000,
        'allowPartialLastRow': true
    };

    // This is just for the case that the browser window is resized
    var resizeTimer = null;
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        resetCollage(); // resize all collages
    });

    // Here we apply the actual CollagePlus plugin
    var collage = function(elems) {
        if (!elems)
            elems = $('.Collage');
        elems.removeWhitespace().collagePlus(collageOpts);
    };

    var resetCollage = function(elems) {
        // hide all the images until we resize them
        $('.Collage .Image_Wrapper').css("opacity", 0);
        // set a timer to re-apply the plugin
        if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            collage(elems);
        }, 200);
    };

    var setFancyBox = function() {
        $(".covers").fancybox({/*options*/});
    };

    this.init = function(opts) {
        if (opts != null) {
            if (opts.height) {
                collageOpts.targetHeight = opts.height;
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // some recursive functional funk
            // basically goes through each section then each image in each section and loads the image and recurses onto the next image or section
            function loadImage(images, imgIndex, sections, sectIndex, callback) {
                if (sectIndex == sections.length) {
                    return callback();
                }
                if (imgIndex == images.length) {
                    var c = sections.eq(sectIndex);
                    collage(c);
                    images = sections.eq(sectIndex + 1).find("img.preload");
                    return loadImage(images, 0, sections, sectIndex + 1, callback);
                }
                var src = images.eq(imgIndex).data("src");
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = img.onerror = function() {
                    images[imgIndex].src = src; // once the image is loaded set the UI element's source
                    loadImage(images, imgIndex + 1, sections, sectIndex, callback)
                };
                img.src = src; // load the image in the background
            }

            var firstImgList = $(".Collage").eq(0).find("img.preload");
            loadImage(firstImgList, 0, $(".Collage"), 0, setFancyBox);
        });
    }
}
```

From my galleries I then call the init function.

It seems like my recursive chain being triggered by img.onload or img.onerror is not working properly if the images take a while to load(on slow networks or mobile).  I'm not sure what I'm missing here so if anyone can chip in that would be great!

If it isn't clear what is going wrong from the code I posted you can see a live example here: https://www.yuvalboss.com/albums/olympic-traverse-august-2017

It works quite well on my desktop, but on my Nexus 5x it does not work and seems like the finally few collage calls are not happening.  I've spent too long on this now so opening this up to see if I can get some help.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: just two hints: your `resetCollage` check: `clearTimeout`doesn't set the pointer to `null`, so do it by yourself: `resizeTimer = null;` --- About slow connection: use Chrome developer tools and set the Network throttling to a slower value, then you can debug on your desktop. Hope this helps!

Comment: @deblocker it doesn't need to set it to null, just resets it to another 200ms so that  collage(elems) can't get called too frequently.  I have tested with dev tools in both chrom and firefox on desktop using throttling and I can't reproduce the issues I am having on mobile.  I think it has something to do specifically with mobile browsers(Can't even reproduce in chromes mobile emulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whooooo I figured it out!
Was getting this issue which I'm still unsure about what it means

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 43ms
```

Moved this into the callback that happens only once all images are loaded

```
 $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    resetCollage(); // resize all collages
});
```

For some reason it was getting called early even if the browser never resized causing collage to get called when no elements existed yet.

If anyone has any informative input as to why I was getting this js violation would be great to know so I can make a better fix but for now this works :):):)